# Group rows based on an order containing multiple items

Tags: c#

Whereas I have the following table:

[list with lists table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axI9x.png)

| order_number | order_status | item_id | item_name | item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | awaiting_payment | 222 | beans | 98.76 |
| 123 | awaiting_payment | 333 | rice | 54.32 |
| 456 | shipped | 222 | beans | 98.76 |
| 456 | shipped | 333 | rice | 54.32 |
| 456 | shipped | 444 | pasta | 76.54 |
| 789 | canceled | 222 | beans | 98.76 |

And considering that the desired json is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "order_number": 123,
        "order_status": "awaiting_payment",
        "lines": [
            {
                "item_id": 222,
                "item_name": "beans",
                "item_price": 98.76
            },
            {
                "item_id": 333,
                "item_name": "rice",
                "item_price": 54.32
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "order_number": 456,
        "order_status": "shipped",
        "lines": [
            {
                "item_id": 222,
                "item_name": "beans",
                "item_price": 98.76
            },
            {
                "item_id": 333,
                "item_name": "rice",
                "item_price": 54.32
            },
            {
                "item_id": 444,
                "item_name": "pasta",
                "item_price": 76.54
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "order_number": 789,
        "order_status": "canceled",
        "lines": [
            {
                "item_id": 333,
                "item_name": "rice",
                "item_price": 98.76
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying in different ways to reproduce this scenario using C#, but I'm not succeeding...

For this, I declared the following model:

```
        public class Order
        {
            public int order_number { get; set; }
            public string order_status { get; set; }
            public List<OrderItems> lines { get; set; }
        }

        public class OrderItems
        {
            public int item_id { get; set; }
            public string item_name { get; set; }
            public decimal item_price { get; set; }
        }
```

To represent the list according to the table, I declared the following model:

```
        public class FullRow
        {
            public int order_number { get; set; }
            public string order_status { get; set; }
            public int item_id { get; set; }
            public string item_name { get; set; }
            public decimal item_price { get; set; }
        }
```

And I added the lines according to the following code:

```
            List<FullRow> row = new List<FullRow>();
            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number=123,
                order_status= "awaiting_payment",
                item_id=222,
                item_name= "beans",
                item_price=98.76M
            });

            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number = 123,
                order_status = "awaiting_payment",
                item_id = 333,
                item_name = "rice",
                item_price = 54.32M
            });

            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number = 456,
                order_status = "shipped",
                item_id = 222,
                item_name = "beans",
                item_price = 98.76M
            });

            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number = 456,
                order_status = "shipped",
                item_id = 333,
                item_name = "rice",
                item_price = 54.32M
            });

            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number = 456,
                order_status = "shipped",
                item_id = 444,
                item_name = "pasta",
                item_price = 76.54M
            });

            row.Add(new FullRow
            {
                order_number = 789,
                order_status = "canceled",
                item_id = 222,
                item_name = "beans",
                item_price = 98.76M
            });
```

Could someone please help me with this task?

Thank you very much in advance.

I've tried several ways, for example according to the following code, but without success:

```
            foreach (Order listItem in row)
            {
                foreach (OrderItems line in listItem)
                {
                    ... my code to create the json...
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `row` is `List<FullRow>` type. While iterating each item, you can't work with

```cs
foreach (Order listItem in row)
```

as `listItem` is `FullRow` but not `Order` type.

From your scenario, you are trying to group by `order_number` or (`order_number` and `order_status`), you can work with *System.Linq* with `.GroupBy()` to group and return the desired result.

For method-based syntax:

```cs
using System.Linq;
var result = row.GroupBy(x => new { x.order_number, x.order_status })
    .Select(x => new Order
            {
                order_number = x.Key.order_number,
                order_status = x.Key.order_status,
                lines = x.Select(y => new OrderItems
                                 {
                                     item_id = y.item_id,
                                     item_name = y.item_name,
                                     item_price = y.item_price
                                 }).ToList()
            })
    .ToList();
```

For query syntax:

```cs
using System.Linq;

var result = (from x in row
            group x by new { x.order_number, x.order_status } into g
            select new  Order
            {
                order_number = g.Key.order_number,
                order_status = g.Key.order_status,
                lines = g.Select(y => new OrderItems
                                 {
                                     item_id = y.item_id,
                                     item_name = y.item_name,
                                     item_price = y.item_price
                                 }).ToList()
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zmYVWD)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me! The code did the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using linq with `GroupBy`

```
var groupedRows = row.GroupBy(x => new { x.order_number, x.order_status })
                     .Select(x => new { x.Key.order_number, x.Key.order_status, lines = x });
```

Explanation:

Group the rows on `order_number` & `order_status`
Take the result and project into desired shape `{ "order_number:"", "order_status":"", "lines":[] }`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your proposal works perfectly too